# Tying an Application Insight metric to a Operation Id

Tags: azure-application-insights

Configuration: I have a metric reporting the request duration, and I have two custom events setup to show the start time and end time, and each event is filled out with pertinent information for the request.

Problem: I have a metric which is reporting long request durations. But the list of insights is not friendly to correlate the metric with the events and dependencies for the operation.

I would like to either find the duration between the two events to identify which operations are taking long, or assign an Operation Id to a metric which would then allow me to filter the list of insights to ones that have high durations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest 2 approaches.
**Approach #1:**
Open Search in Azure portal and filter requests by performance bucket. You can then click on each search result to view correlated events. If predefined buckets don't work for you you can assign your own using telemetry initializer in SDK (please let us know if predefined buckets don't work)

[image]

**Approach #2**
Use Analytics join query to find out telemetry items with chosen operation ID, for example:

```
requests 
| where duration > 5000
| project operation_Name , operation_Id, duration  
| join (traces | project operation_Id,  message ) on operation_Id 
| project operation_Name , message 
| limit 10
```

Comment: Sorry, small detail which complicates both of those approaches. My application uses the OAuth pipeline and therefore the request insights that are reported do not correlate to any of the requests that I am interested in. This is why I have odd metrics/events that are reporting information that would normally be gathered via automatic insights.

Comment: Instead of using custom metrics, I would then use TrackRequest manually to log request duration. As long as operation ID is assigned to all telemetry within the request, you can use the approaches above. Will it work for you?

Comment: After setting up all the filters for this request and building a graph, I was able to successfully identify long running requests identified with operation_id, and then correlate them to the other telemetry on that operation. Thank you very much!